# Automapper not ignore primary key

Tags: automapper

I have two classes:

```
public class AddFrequentQuestionModel

{

   public string Question { get; set; }

   public string Answer { get; set; }

}

public class FrequentQuestion : IEntity

{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Question { get; set; }

    public string Answer { get; set; }

}
```

when wanting to convert AddFrequentQuestionModel to FrequentQuestion

```
var frequentQuestion = _mapper.Map<FrequentQuestion>(model);
```

it shows me the following error:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the source/destination type For no matching constructor, add a no-arg
>   ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>
> AddFrequentQuestionModel -> FrequentQuestion (Destination member list)
>   Calidda.ServiciosCliente.Application.FrequentQuestions.Commands.AddFrequentQuestions.AddFrequentQuestionModel
>   -> Calidda.ServiciosCliente.Domain.FrequentQuestions.FrequentQuestion (Destination member list) Unmapped properties: Id

Can you help me please?

PD: my automapper is configured in the following way:

```
config.CreateMap< AddFrequentQuestionModel, FrequentQuestion >().ForMember(s=>s.Id,opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Comment: Have you tried `var frequentQuestion = _mapper.Map<FrequentQuestion, AddFrequentQuestionModel>(model);` (explicitly stating the destination type)?

Comment: Also, where are you calling `config.CreateMap`? Are we sure that the config is getting applied at runtime?

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett if I tried it that way, but it still does not work

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett I have that configuration                                 config.CreateMap<AddFrequentQuestionModel, FrequentQuestion>()
                        .ForMember(s => s.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());